# Send data from different instances of FragmentA to FragmentB

Tags: android, fragment, communication

The problem as follows. I have 2 `Tabs` with `Fragments`:

Tab1) Multiple instances of FragmentA that need to send data to FragmentB

Tab2) FragmentB needs to receive data from FragmentA and update different views inside it depending on which instant of fragmentA sent the data.

Let's say I have 2 instances of FragmentA and each has a button that counts the clicks and FragmentB has 2 textviews. What I want to do is when button in first instance clicked the first textview in fragmentB updates and respectively seconds instance updates the second textview.

FragmentA has `interface getData(){ public void setData()}`

`MainActivity` has `setData(){fragmentB.updateInfo()}`

FragmentB has `updateInfo(){//if instance1 update textview1, if instance2 update textview2}`

How do I implement my `updateInfo` method to understand which instance of FragmentA called it so I can update different views in it? I guess it has something to do with tags of fragmentA but I cant figure it out.

Comment: (Did you read the description of tag [tag:fragment]?)

Answer (score 0):

Use [greenrobot's event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), to post the data as an event in one fragment and subscribe to that data in the other fragment. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47759494/3808178) for an example.